# Clustering on mixture of text and number using k-means

Tags: python, k-means

I want to do clustering on mixture of number and text for example (x,y) is (100,www.xyz) in python.

I tried from sklearn.cluster import KMeans in python using

```
 kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
```

and getting following error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Please help me.

Comment: How do you define the distance between two example?

Comment: thanks for your response .
I don't know How to  define the distance between text and numeric data in k-means. Is there any clustering method??

Comment: What are you trying to cluster by? If a site is xyz.com & zyx.com then they are clustered? Are you familiar with the basis of k means?

Comment: I want to cluster resources(jpg,css,jpeg,images) with response time.
for examle (1000,192.168.0.16:8080//images/1.jpg)